# Java scheduler is not working after awhile

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, task, scheduler

I have a problem with my scheduler , I want to run my program at specific time.
However, it was working fine but it stoped working i can not specify the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XPRh.png)

my code

```
 import java.util.*;

import java.text.*;
import java.util.TimerTask ;


 
      public class ScheduleTask {
          
          static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
           static Date currentDate=new Date();
           static Timer timer = new Timer();
           
           
       public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
          
          System.out.println("Current Time: " + df.format( currentDate));
     
          //Date and time at which you want to execute
          Date date = df.parse("13:57:35");
          
          timer.schedule(new MyTimeTask(), date);
          
          Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
          c.setTime(date);
          c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
          date=c.getTime();
          System.out.print(date);
          
         
          
          
    }
      
  
   private static class MyTimeTask extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
         System.out.println("Running Task");
         
            System.out.println("Current Time: " +  df.format(currentDate));
    
         timer.cancel();
      
   }}
 
   }
```

Comment: You call `timer.cancel()` inside your timer task?

Comment: yes  this is my code I have post the picture

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: @Aljawharah I was probably not clear. But you seem to schedule a task and then stop it, using `timer.cancel()`. Meaning it won't run again. Which would lead to the issue you're describing

Comment: I added the code can you please review it

Answer (score -1):

You can use TimerTask to do that, here is an example:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StopApp {
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask StopApp = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
};
public StopApp() {

//timer.schedule(exitApp, getDateDiff(new Date("get the actual time"), new Date("get the time you want to stop your app"), TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    //Example
    timer.schedule(StopApp, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+2*1000));//Exits after 2 sec of starting the app

while(true)

    System.out.println("The App still turn");
}

public static Date getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    Date date=new Date(diffInMillies);

    return date;//timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new StopApp();

}
}
```